# Тэг video не работает в safari

Tags: html, видео, safari

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, что тэг видео не работает только в safari. (код написан на vue, filePreview приходит от сервера, на это не обращайте внимание)

```
<video controls playsinline muted loop>
   <source :src="filePreview" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Есть идеи как это пофиксить? Много статей перечитал, ничего толкового не нашел.
Или есть хорошие альтернативы для воспроизведения видео? Может быть, либа в npm

Comment: Что такое `:src` и что такое `filePreview`? Код в таком виде не должен работать вообще ни в одном браузере...

Comment: Не обращайте внимание на filePreview. Это значение приходит с сервера. Сам код на vue написан

Comment: Если это код vue-шаблона, значит отметьте это в вопросе, потому что этот код не является корректным html-кодом. Ну или перепишите на корректный html-код

Comment: А ещё перепроверьте, что проблема именно в теге video, а не, например, в видеофайле. Попробуйте какой-нибудь другой видеофайл

Comment: Я же написал, что на всех браузерах работает, кроме сафари)

Comment: А что значит «не работает»? Что отображается вместо видео, какие ошибки пишет в js-консоли? Отправляет ли вообще браузер запрос на скачивание видеофайла?

Comment: Отображает пустой плеер, и не дает воспроизвести никак

Comment: Насчет js ошибок не могу сказать. У меня нет айфона..

Comment: Ну а на сервер-то хотя бы приходит запрос на скачивание видеофайла от айфона?

Comment: Я не особо понимаю, как это посмотреть на телефоне) Сам файл был загружен на сервер, и от него приходит просто ссылка. А вот как действует это: ```<source :src="filePreview" type="video/mp4" />``` не могу сказать

Comment: попробуй конвертировать в mov. Скорее всего, сафари не может проиграть mp4.

Comment: попробую, спасибо =)